# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame...Domains, protocols and ports must match

Tags: javascript, iframe

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://example.com/jobs/listings/ from frame with URL http://example.com/a/j/jobvite/FrameResize.html?height=1446. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

I'm at a loss as to why I'm getting this error. It happens with jobvite iframe, but the message makes no sense, because the domains, protocals and ports all match.

It works in Firefox, but not in IE, Safari, and Chrome.

Comment: I found my problem. We were explicitly setting 'document.domain=example.com' while using subdomains (ie: test.example.com). commenting out that line of javascript fixes the problem in chrome.

Comment: A safety measure to prevent cross site scripting I'd say.